# Lightboxed image with social overlay

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, lightbox

I've created a filtered gallery with a plugin called GoGalleryPro for Wordpress. When you click on an image a lightbox opens showing the image. 
Whilst the lightbox active i'd visible to be able to have social icons in the bottom left corner.

I've tried a couple of plugins and tried to write a snippet of code myself by no joy. Any guidance would be great!

Here is the link to the page in question;
http://176.32.230.43/wjwhites.co.uk/congress/

Comment: Please note that asking for suggestions or recommendations is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Questions should only be posted after you have **researched your issue and should include your attempts so far along with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/.

You will be able to add custom html within the pop up window.